# Laravel Backpack - How to export PDF together with its details row

Tags: laravel-backpack

I use $this->crud->enableExportButtons() to export automatically. But it can only export the list, not the details. Is there any other way to export the data together with it's details row?

Expected to be able to export all including the details row in a PDF

Answer (score 0):

Export buttons work only on the data table's retrieved results(1st page only).
While each item's details row is another Ajax request. It can't export that's not fetched already.

I recommend creating a custom operation if you want to export a PDF.

- You can find the instructions here in the [docs](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-operations#creating-a-custom-operation-1)
- For bulk operation, visit [here](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-operations#creating-a-new-operation-with-a-bulk-action-no-interface)

You can try the following packages to generate PDFs with ease and use one of them inside your custom operation:

- https://github.com/spatie/laravel-pdf
- https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf